# push based federation in a multi site deployment

Tags: prometheus

I have a multi data center like setup except that they are all deployed in customer sites and I cannot do a pull based federation to get metrics from all sites into one centralized Prometheus setup.  What's the best architecture for this kind of a setup?

I am unable to see how we can push gateway either as it requires individual apps to push metrics to the central push gateway server skipping the onsite Prometheus server. Is there a way we can have onsite Prometheus server push all metrics to the push gateway?

Santosh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such way, as Prometheus doesn't push in that format and the pushgateway isn't intended for that use case. I'd look at approaches such as VPNs or ssh tunnels.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Luckily, it looks like centralized alerting can be implemented as prometheus makes outbound api calls to the alert manager.

Comment: Can PushProx be used for this purpose - federation through NAT?

Comment: Yes, PushProx could be used for that.